# My output is not as per the code and I cannot identify where have I gone wrong

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I am relatively new using R, I wanted to create a new column called Reporting Month (with format: Date) for my table using "case when" statement and the condition is using a column called Period (with format: Character)
The codes executed but the output of the dates only range from 31/01/2020 to 31/12/2020, nothing for 2019 or 2021, can someone help?  If there is a neater way to do it, I would really appreciate for some advice too! Thank you so much!!

```
dt <- dt %>%  mutate(
  Reporting_Month = case_when(
    Period == 'ZZZ-MARCH-2019' ~ as.Date("31/03/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-APRIL-2019' ~ as.Date("30/04/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-MAY-2019' ~ as.Date("31/05/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JUNE-2019' ~ as.Date("30/06/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JULY-2019' ~ as.Date("31/07/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-AUGUST-2019' ~ as.Date("31/08/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-SEPTEMBER-2019' ~ as.Date("30/09/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-OCTOBER-2019' ~ as.Date("31/10/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-NOVEMBER-2019' ~ as.Date("30/11/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-DECEMBER-2019' ~ as.Date("31/12/2019", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JANUARY-2020' ~ as.Date("31/01/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-FEBRUARY-2020' ~ as.Date("29/02/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-MARCH-2020' ~ as.Date("31/03/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-APRIL-2020' ~ as.Date("30/04/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-MAY-2020' ~ as.Date("31/05/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JUNE-2020' ~ as.Date("30/06/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JULY-2020' ~ as.Date("31/07/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-AUGUST-2020' ~ as.Date("31/08/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-SEPTEMBER-2020' ~ as.Date("30/09/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-OCTOBER-2020' ~ as.Date("31/10/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-NOVEMBER-2020' ~ as.Date("30/11/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-DECEMBER-2020' ~ as.Date("31/12/2020", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    Period == 'ZZZ-JANUARY-2021' ~ as.Date("31/01/2021", format("%d/%m/%y")),
    TRUE                      ~  as.Date("31/01/2000")
  )
)
```

Comment: Use 'lubridate::ceiling_date`, things would be much easier then

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate) 

dt %>%  mutate(
  Reporting_Month = ceiling_date(dmy(str_replace(Period, 'ZZZ', '01')), unit = 'month') - days(1))
             Period Reporting_Month
1    ZZZ-APRIL-2019      2019-04-30
2  ZZZ-OCTOBER-2019      2019-10-31
3     ZZZ-JULY-2020      2020-07-31
4 ZZZ-DECEMBER-2021      2021-12-31
5  ZZZ-JANUARY-2021      2021-01-31
```

with a dummy example

```
dt
> dt
             Period
1    ZZZ-APRIL-2019
2  ZZZ-OCTOBER-2019
3     ZZZ-JULY-2020
4 ZZZ-DECEMBER-2021
5  ZZZ-JANUARY-2021
```

Comment: Thanks AnilGoyal, I try with your codes too, but I had an error of Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: have you loaded the `dplyr`.  I didn't specified becuase that's you tagged along

Comment: Yup, I have loaded dplyr a long with the belong: `library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)`  and the results is now NA when I test it out. `tESTp <- tESTp %>% mutate(Reporting_Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(Period,'ZZZ-%b-%Y'),frac = 1))`

Comment: Sorry AnilGoyal, Yours did work!! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `Period` to `yearmon` class and then to Date with `frac = 1` to get last day of the month.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dt %>% mutate(Reporting_Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(Period,'ZZZ-%b-%Y'),frac = 1))

#             Period Reporting_Month
#1    ZZZ-MARCH-2019      2019-03-31
#2     ZZZ-JUNE-2019      2019-06-30
#3  ZZZ-OCTOBER-2019      2019-10-31
#4 ZZZ-DECEMBER-2019      2019-12-31
```

**data**

```
dt <- data.frame(Period = c('ZZZ-MARCH-2019', 'ZZZ-JUNE-2019', 
                            'ZZZ-OCTOBER-2019', 'ZZZ-DECEMBER-2019'))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, it only work when it is displayed on the console but when I try to mutate and add as a column to a data frame, the Reporing_Month in date format is NA.... :(

Comment: @SL22122406 You need to assign the data back to `dt`. Try `dt <- dt %>% mutate(Reporting_Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(Period,'ZZZ-%b-%Y'),frac = 1))` to see the `Reporting_Month` as a new column in your original data.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I did use the above line to create a new column but for some reason, it didn't work, the new columns all return as NA for some bizarre reason.  Thank you so much for your help as well, it is now sorted :)

Comment: I think using `%B` instead of `%b` should work. `dt <- dt %>% mutate(Reporting_Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(Period,'ZZZ-%B-%Y'),frac = 1))`. It is strange though, `%b` worked for me.